# Not a function TypeError when trying to split a user input inside a function

Tags: javascript

I created two functions and a global object data. I am trying to split what a person inputs inside a text area into individual strings and push them in the global object. The Error I have says userInputParam.split is not a function.For the sake of brevity I have excluded the updateUserInput function which is attached to a click event.

```js
let data = {
  userInput: [],
  splittedInput: [],
  slicedInput: [],
};


function updateUserInput(data) {
  if (data.userInput.length == 0) {
    //   console.log("You can do this Panda!")
    data.userInput.push(input.value);
    //input.value is what a user inputs in a textarea. 
    splitUserInput(data.userInput)
  }
}

function splitUserInput (userInputParam){
    let splittedInput = userInputParam.split(/([*/+-])/)
    //console.log(splittedInput)
}
```

Comment: `data.userInput` is an array. There is no `split` on `Array.prototype`

Comment: Maybe you should call `splitUserInput(input.value)`?

Comment: Also, assuming that you want to split the literal characters `*`, `/`, `+` and `-`, you probably need to escape the forward slash by doing `/([*\/+-])/`

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `splitUserInput` should be the input value, not the array that you pushed it onto.

`splitUserInput` should return the result of splitting, and then you can push that onto `data.sp;littedInput`.

```js
function updateUserInput(data) {
  if (data.userInput.length == 0) {
    //   console.log("You can do this Panda!")
    data.userInput.push(input.value);
    //input.value is what a user inputs in a textarea. 
    data.splittedInput.push(splitUserInput(data.userInput));
  }
}

function splitUserInput (userInputParam){
    let splittedInput = userInputParam.split(/([*/+-])/)
    return splittedInput;
}
```